# PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 3): 24 dangerous doors

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2023](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7527). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123454/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-2-wall-i-want-for-christmas) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123481/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-4-a-few-of-my-favourite-things)</sub>

---

Task: Solve the killer sudoku

- Normal sudoku rules apply
- In cages, digits must sum to the small clue on the top left corner of the cage. Digits cannot repeat in a cage.

[Solve on Penpa+](https://swaroopg92.github.io/penpa-edit/#m=solve&p=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)

[image]

Comment: Having seen the solution below, I still don't understand "dangerous".

Comment: @msh210 I think that it's just a reference to the "killer" part. I'm impressed that the puzzle uses precisely the numbers 1-24 exactly once each in order to resemble an advent calendar.

Comment: Yes, I am , too.

Comment: Ooh, I didn't realize that! That's very clever!

Comment: That explains the "doors".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved grid:

> [image: Solved grid]

It was fun!

General solve path:

> Start with the obvious one box clue R3C5 and R8C7, then to the 3-sum on C9. Then the 6-sum on top right box, which must be 1+2+3. The 4-sum on C1 is also solved.
>  Some general strategy is mostly to consider the possible numbers on a cage to get some sure possibilities (e.g., must be 5+7 instead of 4+8), and to consider that total sum in a 3x3 box is 45 (e.g., the mid right box, being covered with all sums, helped to deduce the 22-cage should have a sum of 13 in that box, so can put 9 in R6C6).
>  The longest stuck point was resolving the 20-cage on R3. Eventually I figured that it's either 4 or 9 in R4C1, but dunno which. But figured that 4 will lead to a 7+9 in the remaining two spots, which leaves only 4 as the valid candidate on **both** R3C6 and R3C7, a contradiction. After getting past that, it's easy again.