# PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 4): A few of my favo(u)rite things

Tags: seasonal, connect-wall

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2023](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7527). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123463/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-3-24-dangerous-doors) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123497/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-5-twin-brother-waiters)</sub>

---

A Connect Wall is a set of sixteen words/proper nouns/phrases which can be broken into four groups of four related items. In this holiday-themed Connect Wall, the four categories can be combined to create my favorite Christmas carol, which is the answer to this puzzle.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BALANCE | CAGE | FROST | GOOD |
| HORN | KOB | MANNING | MASON |
| MILLS | MIST | OVERS | RANCHER |
| ROGER | SPARKS | SWILLING | THRESH |

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The categories are

> BALANCE GOOD RANCHER ROGER - words that can be preceded by JOLLY

> KOB MIST OVERS THRESH - words which can take -OLD as a suffix

> HORN MANNING MILLS SWILLING - surnames of great [New Orleans SAINT](https://www.canalstreetchronicles.com/2016/9/11/12874132/top-50-new-orleans-saints-all-time-no-5-1)s

> CAGE FROST MASON SPARKS - surnames of famous NICHOLASs

and your favourite carol is of course

> Jolly Old Saint Nicholas

As for me...

> ... my little brain
>  Isn't very bright;
> Choose for me, dear Santa Claus,
> What you think is right!

Comment: Crushed in detail! Well done!

Answer (score 9):

The four groups are:

> Words that can come after "Jolly":
>  ROGER, RANCHER, GOOD, BALANCE

> Words that can have "old" added at the end:
>  THRESH, OVERS, KOB, MIST

> Famous Nicholas's:
>  [CAGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Cage), [MASON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Mason), [FROST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Frost), [SPARKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Sparks)

> People who played for the New Orleans Saints:
>  [MANNING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archie_Manning), [SWILLING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pat_Swilling), [MILLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Mills), [HORN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Horn)

Therefore, the Christmas carol is:

> Jolly Old Saint Nicholas

Comment: Well done, but just barely sniped! Quoting another famous Christmas movie, "Welcome to the party, pal!"