# PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 7): The Oracle Rambles On and On

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2023](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7527). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123520/) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123552/)</sub>

---

Hadn't heard from the Oracle in a while until this text came in...

[image]

What is the Oracle trying to tell me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Oracle is...

> wishing you a **MERRY XMAS**!

The emojis before the numbers in each line...

> suggest the name of one of [Santa's reindeer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Visit_from_St._Nicholas) in Clement Clarke Moore's 1823 poem, *A Visit from St. Nicholas* (plus Rudolph).
>
>  **COMET** (3)
>  **PRANCER** (6)
>  **RUDOLPH** (1) (from kangaROO DOLPHin)
>  **DUNDER** (6) (the New York Dutch for 'thunder', what you *hear* in a storm)
>  **CUPID** (4)
>  **VIXEN** (3)
>  **BLIXEM*** (6) (New York Dutch for 'lightning', what you *see* in a storm)
>  **DANCER** (2)
>  **DASHER** (3)
>
>  <sup>* The OP points out in comments that the 'time = year' mini-rebus for 'Blixem' should prompt us to note the time that the Oracle posted the message - 18:23 - and equate that with the year of the Clement Clarke Moore poem, to reinforce the source for the alternative 'Blixem' spelling of 'Blitzen'...</sup>

The numbers...

> tell you which letter of that reindeer name to extract (so COMET(3) means the 3rd letter of coMet, which is 'M'). Repeating this for all reindeer gives the answer **MERRI XMAS** - but the mini-rebus after 'CUPID' (i d+i+a+lick+t i.e. "i dialect", with thanks to @DanielS in comments on the other answer) instructs us to replace 'I' with its sometime-soundalike 'Y'.
>
>  The final *final* answer is thus **MERRY XMAS**!

Comment: Nice job. The clock and calendar  were supposed to mean rot13(gvzr = lrne, jvgu gur gvzr gur zrffntr jnf jevggra uvagvat ng gur irefvba bs anzrf gb hfr) but you got that anyway

Comment: @caPNCApn Ah, that's very clever! I even wondered if there was anything hidden up there, because I know you've done things like that in the past with your Oracle puzzles :) I'll add that to the post for posterity...

Answer (score 8):

The oracle is telling you

> Merry Xmas

The rebus are just hinting at the 9 reindeers

In order

> Comet

> Prancer

> Rudolph (kange Roo + Dolph in)

> Donner (Ear+Lightningbolt) is a heard lightning bolt which is Thunder and Donner is Thunder in German

> Cupid

> Vixen

> Blitzen (Eye+Lightning bolt) which is is a seen bolt which is Lightning which is Lightning in German

> Dancer

> Dasher

Take all the numbers with the rebus and and take the letter it corresponds to with each answer of the rebus you get

> MERRI XTAS

Now the rebus for T is that time or t is equal to M (Month)

Not sure about the I to Y

Comment: Long time no see :) It was only when I went to click 'Post' on my answer that I spotted yours here (I'd been composing mine on mobile and spent too long trying to resolve the 'diatonguet' word...) and I see you also had trouble translating the additional rebuses as well...! Please do remember to use spoiler blocks in answers to puzzles, thanks :)

Comment: D - EYE - A - LICK - T = dialect I think

Comment: Nice job. I accepted the other answer because it is a little closer to the intended solution.